# Calculating correct longitude when it's over |180|?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to develop a "formula" to correct the lat-lng values.

I'm using vue-leaflet but when you pan outside the "first" world you get big numbers. Over +180 or under -180.

For example: when I pan to America to the right (east direction), I get as lng 215.
In my mind, I would just correct it with `215-360=-145`

The same is for when I pan to east russia to the left (west direction) and I get for example -222. Now I need to calculate `-222+360=138`

However, since the world is indefinite the user could pan to the 8th world and I had to adjust the values.

Is it possible to calculate the right longitude? (and another requirement is when the user is in the first world, 24 lng should still be 24 lng.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to repeatedly add (or subtract) 360 to your value until it lies in the range of -180 - 180. So usually a pair of loops like:

```
lon = -187;
while(lon < -180){
  lon +=360;
}
while (lon > 180){
  lon -= 360;
}
```

Comment: signs wrong way round? Should be lon +=360 in first case.

Comment: you can do it with only one loop ```while (Math.abs(lon) > 180) { lon -= Math.sign(lon) * 360 }``` I am not providing it as an answer though because your version actually matches the explanation, while my version is just an optimization that likely doesn't make any difference. I keep it as a comment only as a reminder that things can be done in multiple ways, some more optimized than others.

Comment: I don't think I would ever use that one as it uses 2 function calls per loop and only one of my loops would ever execute. Probably makes no difference in this example but that's my prejudice

Comment: while they look like functions, Math functions in JavaScript should be seen more like operators with verbose symbols. In this sense we can also see +- and even < as functions as well. Edit: I had a solution here that it didn't actually work

Comment: You can't do `lon %= 180`?

Comment: @NicHartley That will convert -187 to -7, which is incorrect. The two-loop solution is best.

Answer (score 21):

An answer that avoids conditionals and function calls:

```
longitude = (longitude % 360 + 540) % 360 - 180
```

I wrote a quick microbenchmark at https://jsperf.com/longitude-normalisation and the conditional code seems to be faster (in Chrome on my machine) for 'reasonable' ranges of input values.  In general you probably shouldn't be worrying in advance about performance in small calculations like this, giving more weight to readability and consistency with the rest of your codebase.

Probably more important in this case is the question of whether your code could ever come across extreme input values (1e10, Infinity etc.).  If so, the looping implementation could end up running *really* slowly or silently hanging your program.  This might occur with calculations performed near the poles, e.g. trying to pan east or west by some *distance* (rather than angle) from a pole could easily result in an infinite longitude.

Comment: Interesting. Let's race a conditional jmp against a FP divide. Hmmm I wonder.

Comment: @Joshua You can't use a conditional jump. You have to use *multiple conditional jumps*, aka a loop. (Plus the loop contains floating point additional, which isn't free.) How many iterations the loop needs depends on the input. So you have to know something about the data to look at performance. If the vast majority are near the desired range and require few iterations, sure, the addition loop might be faster, but it isn't as obvious as your sarcasm suggests.

Comment: @jpmc26: In this case, expecting to go around the loop more than once is silly.

Comment: There was no sarcasm. I actually don't know which way it would fall.

Comment: @Joshua yep, I wasn't sure either :).  I added more to the answer on performance (and a potential failure case of the loop code)

Comment: This does not work if your input longitude is exactly 180

Comment: @DoRe this normalises to the range `[-180, 180)` which is not inconsistent with anything specified in the question.

Answer (score 5):

One-liner:

```
normalized = remainder(longitude, 360);
```

Explanation: You want to know what remains after you disregard full rotations (360°).

This process is called normalizing.

[Example (cpp.sh)](http://cpp.sh/7uy2v)

Comment: Wouldn't this result in a [0, 360) value, not [-180, 180] as Shadrix requested?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Check this example: http://cpp.sh/7uy2v

Comment: Ah, didn't know this was C++. In Shadrix's context of JavaScript, I interpreted `remainder` as `modulus`. Modulus in JS would result in [0, 360).

Comment: I don't think that would work. You would need to subtract 360 iff result > 180. Another problem I just realized with JavaScript is that modulo is symmetrical across 0, e.g. `-1 % 3` is -1, not 2 as would be necessary for it to work here. `remainder` is a great C++ solution, but unfortunately there's just no function/operator in JS that's similar enough to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: longitude = atan2(cos(long), sin(long))

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good idea. It's very hard to understand, computationally expensive and potentially subject to rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

If the programming language you're using supports the % (mod) operator on floating point numbers (like Python and Ruby), I'd recommend using that.  Otherwise, some other languages (like C and C++) allow you to use fmod().

(Whichever mod operator you use, make sure ahead of time that it will do mod operations on floating-point numbers, and that it'll always give you non-negative answers.  Otherwise you'll get a nasty surprise later when many of your lat/lon points are not correct.)

Use it like this:

```
# Put the longitude in the range of [0,360):
longitude %= 360

# Put the longitude in the range of [-180,180):
if longitude >= 180:
    longitude -= 360
```

If you'd prefer to do it all in one line:

```
# Put the longitude in the range of [-180,180):
longitude = (longitude + 180) % 360 - 180
```

These approaches have no loops, so they'll normalize longitude values without needing to repeatedly add or subtract, no matter how many times your observation has circled around the earth.

## Edit:

Hmmm... I just noticed that Javascript doesn't seem to handle `%` with negative values like I thought it would.

In that case, try this one-liner:

```
longitude = (longitude + 36180) % 360 - 180
```

The `36180` we're adding is 36,000 + 180.  The 36,000 is to move a negative value into the positive domain, and the 180 is to shift it over so that when it is modded by `360`, it'll be in the range of [0,360).  The `- 180` part shifts it back to the range of [-180,180).

Here's another one-liner, one that doesn't rely on 36,000 being big enough:

```
longitude = (longitude % 360 + 360 + 180) % 360 - 180
```

The `longitude % 360 + 360` part will ensure the value stays in the positive domain when it's later modded by `360`.  The `+ 180` part shifts it over so that when it later gets 180 subtracted from it (with `- 180`), it'll be in the desired range of [-180,180).

Comment: Note: C,C++ `fmod(longitude, 360)` --> (-360.0 ... +360.0) and `ilongitude % 360` --> [-359 ... +359].

Comment: @chux - I didn't know about that, so I just tested it, and it appears that you are correct.  Thank you for pointing that out.